# Calculate sales tax Rate U.S./Canada in Excel: If pre-tax amount, sales tax amount paid, grand total paid, but UNKNOWN Sales Tax Rate?

Tags: percentages

1. I need to create a calculation for Excel or on paper to (not a website or app):
   Partial refunds and sales tax to apply without knowing the U.S. State’s Sales Tax Rate.

Example of problem: If I know my subtotal is: $\$27.99$ And my Tax Amount is: $\$1.96$ How can I know that the Tax RATE is: $7.00\%$ ?

Excel: How do I express this in a formula in Excel allowing for manual entry of field 1 (pre-tax amt), field 2 (tax amt paid) = Rate

2. For Canadian refunds need for Excel formula: GST, PST (Federal Rate 8%, Provincial Rate 5%) are needed some times together, a calculation with IF statement (if GST, then 8%, IF PST 5%, IF GST AND PST then 13%).

Research: Website has a calculator tool that is an example:

1. http://www.csgnetwork.com/salestaxpercentcalc.html
2. http://www.calculconversion.com/sales-tax-calculator-gst-qst.html

Comment: $\dfrac{1.96}{27.99}\approx 0.0700$

Comment: Thank you for fast reply, Henry! (You also helped me to rephrase my question a little better) I appreciate your answer.

Comment: In case it helps, an initial translation from verbal to math is: $1.96$ is what percent of $27.99$? Letting $r$ be the number of percentage points (i.e. if the percentage is 7.2%, then $r=7.2),$ we can rewrite this as: $1.96 = (r\%)(27.99)$ (translating "is" as =, and translating "of" as multiplication). Dividing both sides by 27.99 (to isolate $r\%)$ gives $\frac{1.96}{27.99} = r\%,$ which becomes $0.070025\ldots = r\%.$ Since $r\%$ is interpreted as $\frac{r}{100},$ we get (after multiplying both sides by $100)$ $7.0025\ldots = r.$

Comment: Thank you, Dave!